# Eclipse RCP, Spring, Hibernate Class Loading Issue

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipse-rcp, osgi, eclipse-gemini

I’m developing a RCP based app that uses a data access layer implemented using Spring Data JPA backed by hibernate. The annotated domain classes are in one jar/bundle, the Spring repositories and spring config to instantiate the datasource, entity manager, and transaction manager are in another bundle.These jars are used by other non-RCP apps across the project.I have all of the hibernate 3.6.8 jars and dependencies either wrapped and exposed through my own plugins or as OSGI bundles (jta, antlr, commons collections, etc) in the target platform. I’m using Eclipse Gemini Blueprint to manage the bundle spring contexts within the RCP app.

When the DAL bundle spring context is being initialized by the gemini extender, I get Hibernate related ClassDefNotFound exceptions, usually either on org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence or javax.persistence.spi.Persistenceprovider. I’ve tried putting all of the hibernate jars and dependencies in a single plugin that exports the javax and hibernate packages. I’ve tried setting Eclipse Buddy policies in the manifests of the plugins that I have control over, etc.

I haven’t been able to find any solution to this class loading issue between Spring and Hibernate under Eclipse RCP using Gemini. I’ve done past hibernate DAO projects within RCP by putting all of the hibernate jars in the same plugin as my domain and DAO classes, so only my classes are exported.

At this point I don’t think moving to a more OSGI friendly JPA provider like OpenJPA or EclipseLink is an option.

I found an answer to a slightly related question that suggested putting all of the spring jars and dependencies into a single plugin, with the hibernate jars and dependencies in another plugin with buddy policies set. This seems dirty when most of the jars involved are OSGi bundles.

I suppose I could create a plugin that holds the DAL jar, hibernate jars, and spring ORM jars, so they can all see each other.

Is there a clean way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The core bundle if you own it, add all the suspected bundles as registered buddies and make sure that you have defined packages or bundles are reuired otherwise sometimes buddy class loading is not going to work. If the loading is initiated from you bundle the eclipse buddy policy should cascade. Other option would be to modify the manfiest files in target bundles that are causing issues.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I took a similar approach to what you describe to get a JPA DAO solution working with Hibernate, but no Spring Data JPA, by bundling the Hibernate jars and dependencies in a single plugin and using buddy loading with my domain model plugin and DAO plugin. I didn't want to modify any third party manifests as that isn't a good maintenance option. So the bottom line is I abandoned using Spring Data JPA in the Eclipse RCP environment due to classloader issues.